# What are the various attribute options for ion-badge in ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

The default color for  is blue.

Applying attributes like assertive or positive has no impact on the badge.
Does anyone know the options available to use with ion-badge ?

```
  //still remains blue
 <ion-badge assertive>260k</ion-badge>
```

Comment: What are assertive and positive supposed to do? I do not find those keywords in the documentation of Ionic 2. And which attributes have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

By adding an attribute, e.g. `secondary`, you will change it to green.

```
 <ion-badge assertive secondary>260k</ion-badge>
```

The currently available tags for coloring are defined in [how to theme your app](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/)

Other than that, you also have the `item-left` and `item-right` attributes you can use to align the badge. There are currently no other documentation on how to add more than those. See the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#badges) for more details